# query_posts year parameter returns 0 posts

Tags: wordpress

I have a custom post type displaying posts in the `archive-CPT-name.php` template file and need to filter posts by year. When the query_var `archive` is present, the below code is added prior to the loop:

```
global $query_string;
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
$archive_year = get_query_var('archive', false);
query_posts( $query_string . '&year='.$archive_year.'&paged='.$paged );
```

This returns 0 posts. If I change `year='.$archive_year.'` to `day=16`, keeping everything else the same, then I correctly get the posts created on the 16th. I'm also able to filter by `w` and `monthnum` successfully. It's only the `year` parameter that doesn't work.

Any ideas why this might be happening?

Edit: `$wp_query->request` includes the following SQL `... WHERE 1=1 AND ( YEAR( wp_posts.post_date ) = 2016 ) AND ( 0 = 1 ) ...`. Why is the `AND ( 0 = 1 )` being included? Where might that be coming from? It looks like it may be the cause of my issue.

Update: I'm using the following code as a workaround, but would rather figure out why the above code doesn't work.

```
<?php
  $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
  $archive_year = get_query_var('archive', false);
  $args = array('post_type' => 'repair-post', 'date_query' => array(array('year'  => $archive_year)), 'paged' => $paged);
  $loop = new WP_Query( $args );

  if ($loop->have_posts()) :
    while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : 
?>
```

Comment: All my research indicates that the `AND (0=1)` is due to an undefined / incorrect taxonomy query.  However, year doesn't seem to be a taxonomy.... can you remove the other pieces from the query and see what happens? (paged)

Comment: @cale_b Any `query_posts()` variation that included 'year=####' (with any year number), gave the same result. That includes simply `query_posts('year=2016');`. I've updated my question with a workaround, but as it requires additional code + customized pagination, I'd much rather get this working with query_posts